# Error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mywebsite1' while deploying to Python Anywhere

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

Hi I'm trying to deploy my portfolio website to Python Anywhere but I'm still getting an error:  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mywebsite1'. I ran through the [doc](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/), but still can't find a solution.

My dir sctructure look like this:

```
`-- mywebsite1/
    |-- manage.py
    `-- app/
        `-- urls.py
        `-- views.py
    `-- mywebsite1/
        `-- __init__.py
        `-- asgi.py
        `-- settings.py
        `-- urls.py
        `-- wsgi.py
    `-- templates/
    `-- static/
```

My WSGI configuration file looks like that:

```
# +++++++++++ DJANGO +++++++++++
# To use your own django app use code like this:
import os
import sys
#
## assuming your django settings file is at '/home/lusocpb/mysite/mysite/settings.py'
## and your manage.py is is at '/home/lusocpb/mysite/manage.py'
path = '/home/lusocpb/portfolio/mywebsite1'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
#
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mywebsite1.settings'
# then:
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Error I'm getting:

```
Error running WSGI application
2024-02-25 16:16:46,110: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mywebsite1'
2024-02-25 16:16:46,110:   File "/var/www/lusocpb_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 27, in <module>
2024-02-25 16:16:46,110:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2024-02-25 16:16:46,110: 
2024-02-25 16:16:46,111:   File "/home/lusocpb/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2024-02-25 16:16:46,111:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2024-02-25 16:16:46,111: 
2024-02-25 16:16:46,111:   File "/home/lusocpb/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2024-02-25 16:16:46,111:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2024-02-25 16:16:46,111: 
2024-02-25 16:16:46,111:   File "/home/lusocpb/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
2024-02-25 16:16:46,111:     self._setup(name)
2024-02-25 16:16:46,111: 
2024-02-25 16:16:46,111:   File "/home/lusocpb/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in _setup
2024-02-25 16:16:46,111:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2024-02-25 16:16:46,112: 
2024-02-25 16:16:46,112:   File "/home/lusocpb/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 217, in __init__
2024-02-25 16:16:46,112:     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
```

After printing sys.path in venv console:

```
>>> print(sys.path)
['/var/www', '/usr/local/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/home/lusocpb/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages', '/home/lusocpb/portfolio/mywebsite
1']
```

Comment: Is that directory structure that you showed in `/home/lusocpb/portfolio`?

Comment: Also, check [this help page](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/) and make sure you reloaded the web app after making changes in the wsgi file.